# C# MD5 calculation issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, md5

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.0. I want to find the most efficient way to calculate the MD5 result for the whole content of a txt file.

What is the most efficient solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something as simple as:

```
using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    return md5.ComputeHash(stream);
}
```

Given that there's no way of avoiding reading every byte of the stream, I doubt that you'll find anything significantly more efficient.

Comment: Jon, could you please not reply so darn fast all the time :)

Comment: That is called Experience I guess ;)

Comment: I wonder - does ComputeHash() read the stream byte-by-byte or in blocks? In the first case there is some room for optimization.

Comment: @Vilx: While I haven't checked, I'd be amazed if it didn't do it in an efficient way.

Comment: @Brian: I gave you about 2 minutes. What more could you ask for? ;)

Comment: @Vilx: I think `ComputeHash` reads the stream in 4KB chunks, not byte-by-byte.

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
string hash=System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename), "MD5")
```