# Fastest way to get a random value from a string array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, .net-2.0

What's the fastest way to get a random value from a string array in C# on the .net 2.0 framework? I figured they might have had this:

```
string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
fileLines.GetRandomValue();
```

Yes, I know GetRandomValue() is not an actual method, is there something similar that's more or less equally short and sweet?

Comment: what do you mean with: getrandomvalue()?   Should it return a random line of the array?

Comment: I guess you want to calculate some kind of hash value? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388702/c-md5-calculation-issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not built in, but easy enough to add...

```
static readonly Random rand = new Random();
public static T GetRandomValue<T>(T[] values) {
    lock(rand) {
        return values[rand.Next(values.Length)];
    }
}
```

(the `static` field helps ensure we don't get repeats if we use it in a tight loop, and the `lock` keeps it safe from multiple callers)

In C# 3.0, this could be an extension method:

```
public static T GetRandomValue<T>(this T[] values) {...}
```

Then you could use it exactly as per your example:

```
string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
string val = fileLines.GetRandomValue();
```

Comment: Another way to do it is to make rand [ThreadStatic] and use a seed that is derived from system time and ThreadID, and avoid locking altogether ...

Comment: Personally, I think it's a bit of an abuse of extension methods to add this as one. It's clearly not required for all string[] arrays within the application.

Comment: I only said "could", to illustrate the usage from the OPs question, and extension methods have no cumulative cost on code performance. The container class could be in a "Utils.Arrays" namespace, for example, tightly limiting scope.

Comment: I know; but I just think it's a classic example of why extension methods are bad : it's too easy to add useless ones to solve specific problems, rather than adding new general functionality for the benefit or your entire app.

Comment: This was pretty helpful for an application I wrote that needed to select random elements from all sorts of different Lists and arrays; so not useless in that context.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed.

```
Random m = new Random();
string line = fileLines[m.Next(0, fileLines.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
fileLines [new Random ().Next (fileLines.Length)]
```

Comment: Calling this multiple times in quick succession (for example, in a tight loop) will return the same line every time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think arrays support such a function. The easiest way is just to get a random number, and get the corresponding item.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
String item = fileLines[rnd.next(fileLines.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq To Sql way

```
var rFile = fileLines.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you see error you should add System.Linq;

Answer (score 0):

I'd have used this method to get random item from an array :

```
string[] str = {"red","blue","pink","yellow","green","brown"};
int i = new Random.Next(0, str.length);
MessageBox.Show(str[i]);
```