# Pick Random String From Array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, random

How do I go about picking a random string from my array but not picking the same one twice.

```
string[] names = { "image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image4.png", "image5.png" };
```

Is this possible? I was thinking about using

```
return strings[random.Next(strings.Length)];
```

But this has the possibility of returning the same string twice. Or am I wrong about this? Should I be using something else like a `List` to accomplish this. Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: That sounds like you want to *shuffle* the array, and then just iterate over the array normally. There are lots of shuffling questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Atrljoe - You do understand that returning the same string twice would be a random result right?  If you don't want to get the same result twice what you want cannot be described as a random result.

Comment: @Ramhound of course it would be random. It wouldn't be a sequence of *independent* events, but it would still be random.

Comment: @ramhound I understand its not completely random, but in this case, if I ask a user to pick a image, and it returns all the same images randomly (very unlikely but theoretically possible) then the user has no choice. I dont need it to be perfect just enough to get me random looking results.

Comment: I have answered this

[random item from an array][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392819/fastest-way-to-get-a-random-value-from-a-string-array-in-c

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The simplest way (but slow for large lists) would be to use a resizeable container like `List` and remove an element after picking it. Like:

```
var names = new List<string> { "image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image4.png", "image5.png" };

int index = random.Next(names.Count);
var name = names[index];
names.RemoveAt(index);
return name;
```

When your list is empty, all values were picked.

A faster way (especially if your list is long) would be to use a shuffling algorithm on your list. You can then pop the values out one at a time. It would be faster because removing from the end of a `List` is generally much faster than removing from the middle. As for shuffling, you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c) for more details.

Comment: @samb8s Yes, but I was faster :)

Comment: Note that this is potentially a bad idea if the list is long. Removing an item from near the beginning of a long list has to move all the items after it.

Answer (score 38):

Try this code below

```
string[] Titles = { "Excellent", "Good", "Super", "REALLY GOOD DOCTOR!", "THANK YOU!", "THE BEST", "EXCELLENT PHYSICIAN", "EXCELLENT DOCTOR" };

comments_title.Value=Titles[new Random().Next(0,Titles.Length) ] ;
```

Comment: In the future, try to add a little more description to your posts.  Good idea though!  :)

Comment: I always thought that all comments were honest and not automated and those that received good reviews were actually good.

Comment: if it picks max value (Titles.Length) this will cause IndexOutOfRangeException. Otherwise it works well. (Just do Titles.Length - 1)

Comment: @Gober The upper limit is exclusive, so that won't be a problem: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why I generate that always give me same number?
https://dotnetfiddle.net/1C9CcL

Comment: Do not use `new Random()` inside a for loop, It will give you same number every time as it is called too soon. Declare a Random object outside the loop and use that reference inside the loop.

Answer (score 5):

You can shuffle the array in a first step, and then simply iterate over the shuffled array.
This has the advantage of being O(n) compared to O(n^2) the `RemoveAt` based implementations have. Of course this doesn't matter much for short arrays.

Check Jon Skeet's answer to the following question for a good(all orders are equally likely) implementation of shuffe: [Is using Random and OrderBy a good shuffle algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/c-is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm/1287572#1287572)

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is just create a duplicate list, then as you randomly pick out a string, you can remove it from the duplicate list so that you can't pick it twice.

Answer (score 2):

The logic you could use is as follows:

1) Pick a random integer over the range equal to the length of your array. You can do this using the System.Random class.

2) Use the string corresponding to that array index

3) Delete the item with that index from the array (may be easier with a list)

Then you can pick again and the same string won't appear. The array will be one element shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to keep track of the ones you have used, preferably in a `List` if you don't want/can't to modify the original array. Use a `while` loop to check that it hasn't been used, and then add it to the "used" list.

Comment: OK, suppose there are a thousand items in the original list, and 999 items in the "used" list. Your plan is to keep on generating random numbers until you hit the one in a thousand?  Your list picking algorithm is going to get slower and slower. This is a poor algorithm for longer lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
//SET LOWERLIMIT
cmd = new SqlCommand("select min(sysid) as lowerlimit from users", cs);
int _lowerlimit = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
lowerlimit = _lowerlimit;

//SET UPPERLIMIT
cmd = new SqlCommand("select max(sysid) as upperlimit from users", cs);
int _upperlimit = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
upperlimit = _upperlimit;

//GENERATE RANDOM NUMBER FROM LOWERLIMIT TO UPPERLIMIT
Random rnd = new Random();
int randomNumber = rnd.Next(lowerlimit, upperlimit+1);

//DISPLAY OUTPUT
txt_output.Text += randomNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below utility method

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static T PickRandom<T>(this List<T> enumerable)
    {
        int index = new Random().Next(0, enumerable.Count());
        return enumerable[index];
    }
}
```

Then call the below way

```
string[] fruitsArray = { "apple", "orange"};
string inputString = fruitsArray.ToList().PickRandom();
```