# How to pick one random string from given strings?

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I make a program that will pick one random string from given strings like this:

```
int x;
x = Random.Range(0,2);
string[] Quest0 = {"You","Are","How","Hello"};
string[] Quest1 = {"Hey","Hi","Why","Yes"};
string[] Quest2 = {"Here","Answer","One","Pick"};
```

I would like to print out like this:
if x = 2 it would print out Quest2 and so on.

Thank you!

Comment: Put Quest0, Quest1 and Quest2 in an array or List<string[]> and use x as the index you print.

Comment: Yes, but how can I do that? @adamdc78

Comment: do a google search! come on this is actually quite simple show some more effort.. here is an example I saved you some time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695187/pick-random-string-from-array

Comment: "adamdc78" already told you how to do that. Are you asking how to code that?? :|

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca(VS.80).aspx

Comment: its not a jagged array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<String[]> quests = new ArrayList<String[]>();
quests.add(0, new string[]{"You","Are","How","Hello"});
quests.add(1, new string[]{"Hey","Hi","Why","Yes"});
quests.add(2, new string[]{"Here","Answer","One","Pick"});
int x = new Random().nextInt((2 - 0) + 1);
System.out.println(quests.get(x).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Fistly you need to declare a random variable.

```
Random random = new Random();
```

this will create a variable in which you can now get random numbers from. to get random numbers you will use `random.next(x,y)` or in your case `random.next(0,3)` because the final argument is exclusive, so if you want 0, 1 or 2, you must use `(0,3)`.

you then need to make some conditional statments, i would use If statments, to accomplish your goal use something like this:

```
 if (x == 2) 
        {
            foreach (string s in Quest2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
```

Do this for each possible outcome and it will print out all of the values in your array of strings. Hope I have been helpful, thanks.

Also if you new become familiar with these links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx