# Selecting a random variable from a array

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, synthesizer

I am currently trying to make a array with 3 possible values of text like hi, hello, and hey for speech synthesizer I just don't know how would I make it say one of those values randomly?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pick Random String From Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695187/pick-random-string-from-array)

Comment: please consider doing a small search before posting your question, these type of basic questions are already asked by people! you can go check them out and upvote an answer that works for you!

Comment: I did I don't know why I didn't seem to come across that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code:

```
string[] words=new string[]{"hi","Hello","Hey"};

Random r = new Random();
int i= r.Next(0, 2);

string randomWord= words[i];
```