# How to randomize variables from arrays in a rock, paper, scissors game in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I am making a rock, paper, scissors game. I am using an array to the three variables and am trying to randomize the outcome and compare the random string to the user input. I have tried many methods with the random function and the one in the code makes the most sense to me, but it doesn't work. I am trying to make this code as concise as possible. I have seen other ways of creating this game, but they seem inefficient to me. I believe sticking with an array will allow my code to shorten and run faster. Please help me out and guide me on the right direction, thank you.

```
 using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{


    class MyArray
    {




        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var array = new string[] { "rock", "paper", "scissors" };
            var array = new Random();


            Console.WriteLine("Rock, paper, or scissors?");
            string rps = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (rps)
            {
                case "Rock":
                //??
                    break;
                case "Paper":
                //??
                    break;
                case "Scissors":
                //??
                    break;
            }

        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pick Random String From Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695187/pick-random-string-from-array)

Comment: Take a look at [enums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: What specifically are you asking?

Answer (score -1):

In C# we use the System.Random class to generate a random value that you can use to select from an array or `case` logic. 
What you want to use is the `.Next(int)` method to get the index to select from an array.

See me docs on rand: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8

Once you have the ai response value, we can use simple comparison logic and print out the result.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class MyArray
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var array = new string[] { "rock", "paper", "scissors" };
            var rand = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Rock, paper, or scissors?");
            string rps = Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Trim();   // simple sanitation

            var aiResponse = array[rand.Next(array.Length)]; // this is the PC's response
            Console.WriteLine(" PC plays: {0}", aiResponse);

            // Now compare input to ai
            if (rps == aiResponse)
                Console.WriteLine("Draw!!!");
            else
            {
                bool win = false;
                switch (rps.ToLower())
                {
                    case "rock":
                        win = aiResponse == "scissors";
                        break;
                    case "paper":
                        win = aiResponse == "rock";
                        break;
                    case "scissors":
                        win = aiResponse == "paper";
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new ApplicationException("invalid input, expected: rock, paper or scissors");
                }

                if (win)
                    Console.WriteLine("You win!");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("You lose!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. So I am confused what you mean by having an ai response value. Do I have to assign a variable to it? When I typed this code, it gave me an error that aiResponse does not make sense in the context. Thank you

Comment: You code doesn't compile.

Comment: Sorry @JimmyLimmy, I've updated to code example (writing code in the mobile view is a bit tricky sometimes). I am assuming that you want the user to play against the computer program, the AI. So the AI response is the computers selection to play against the user